# Pick optimize minimum number of elements to span a region

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have an optimization problem. I have never learned algorithms, only taught myself python, so I am not sure if this is a hard or easy problem to solve. The non-abstract application of this problem is determining the cheapest way to sequence DNA using available reagents. Now the problem...

There is a circular region, say 0-10, where 10 loops back to 0. There are elements of length 1, which each spans part of the region and the ultimate goal is to minimize the number of elements while covering every position. I have a number of elements of length 1, but these elements do not cover the whole region. Therefore, I will need to add additional elements, at a cost.

So the final cost would be something like *(number of elements) + 2(number of elements purchased)* and the goal would be to minimize cost. Is this an easy problem to solve, or would it require a significant effort to solve it?

[image: example data]

So in this example, I would pick add a value at about 2 and 5.75, and remove some values at about 2.5.

Comment: Do you also want to throw out overlapping existing elements, or can you keep those?

Comment: I want to minimize the number of elements - so throw out as many as possible

Answer (score 2):

I don't know python, but I can help you with pseudo-code. This might not be *perfectly optimal* for your constraints, but you can tweak it around if needed.

Let's assume your elements have two properties, `begin` and `end`, which define the X-coordinate where they respectively, well, begin and end! (Even though your end is always begin+1. If an element starts at 9.5, consider it ending at 10.5 instead of 0.5)

Put all your elements into an array elem[] and sort them with lower `begin` first. Copy the first element and put it at the end of the array increasing `10` on both its `begin` and `end` coordinates. (so it might become something like 10.2 through 11.2) This is to cover the circular aspect of your problem, we use it just for reference but do not count it twice in costs.

```
X = 0  (the farthest you have got covered so far)
foreach element i in array, in order, except for last element:
  if elem[i+1].begin <= X
    continue; // this means you dont need the current element, discard it and go to the next iteration of the loop.
  if elem[i].begin <= X
    X = elem[i].end // you will use this element to expand your reach
  else // bad news, you got an empty hole
    add_elements += ceil(elem[i].begin - X)  // ceil = round up to an integer number of elements needed to cover the hole
    X = elem[i].end // you will use this element anyway!

if X < 10 // after the loop ends
  add_elements += ceil(elem[last].begin - X)
```

You can rewrite the last if/else to require just an `if`, I just thought this way would be more didactic and easier to understand.

`add_elements` contains how many extra elements you need to add. The `ceil()` function is so that if you have a continuous hole of length 2.4, you know you need at least 3 new elements to fix that.

This algorithm is fairly simple and quick, time complexity of O(n logn) due to initial sorting, since I do not know how many elements you need to handle. You can't get it any cheaper than this with floating point coordinates.

**`Possibility of improvement:`** When you know there is a hole that you must add new elements to fix, it might be possible to discard a previously picked element, either at the beginning and/or end of a hole. For example, consider elements {(0,1), (0.7, 1.7), (1.8, 2.8), (2,3)}. There is a hole of length 0.1 between the second and third elements, but if you add a new element of length 1 and place it between 1.0 and 2.0, you can actually throw out both second and third elements.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try and implement it and report back.